# Is there only one valid r,s,parity for a given transaction signed by one private key?

Tags: signature, cryptography, ecrecover, secp256k1

As I understand it in secp256k1 there are infinitely many secrets which, for the same message to be signed, can lead to a valid signature. So the same private key can sign the exact same message and hand out different *r*, *s* and parity values and yet be verified fine.

What I'd like to know is if this is applicable to Ethereum. More specifically: is it possible to sign the exact same transaction with the exact same private key, using different means, and end up with several *r* and *s* value which may all still give back the correct public key / signing address?

I know that the implementation of Ethereum in Go, for example, uses RFC6979 *(Deterministic Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)*.

But what if an implementation doesn't?  Is it thinkable that, say, an hardware wallet would use a non-deterministic way to generate *r* and *s*?  Which would mean, for example, that that hardware wallet may be doing data exfiltration through carefully crafted *r* and *s* value that would be seemingly innocuous?

As a side, but related, question: is it possible to know if a signature was generated following RFC6979?